# Svnadmin load from svn 1.4 to 1.7

Tags: svn, centos

I am attempting to upgrade and migrate a remote subversion server from 1.4 to 1.7

I started by dumping the repositories from the old server

```
svnrdump dump https://path/to/myRepo > myRepo.out
```

I then created a new svn repo on my new server

```
svnadmin create /svn/myRepo
```

And then I tried to load the dump file into it

```
svnadmin load /svn/myRepo < myRepo.out
```

This gets the first few revisions in, but then I get this error

```
svnadmin: E125012: Invalid character in hex checksum
```

The current server is running subversion 1.4.0 on a linux OS (likely CentOS 5 or 6), and the new one is CentOS 7 with svn 1.7.14

I am attempting to do the migration without root access to the old server, but I do have it on the new server. Any ideas on what could be causing this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and foremost, you must run [`svnadmin verify`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.verify.html) on your old server to check the repositories for integrity and consistency.

Instead of running [`svnrdump`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.tk.svnrdump) remotely, you'd better run [`svnadmin dump`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.dump.html) to generate the history dump stream and transfer it to the new computer. Load it to a new repository with [`svnadmin load`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.load.html).

Note that dump stream generated by `svnadmin dump` or `svnrdump dump` does not contain anything except revision history. You will need to move the hook scripts (if any) to the new repository manually.

As a side note, you should understand that you are now upgrading from a very-very old and unsupported SVN 1.4 instance to another old SVN 1.7 instance. SVN 1.7 is not supported anymore and does not receive bug and security fixes. Instead of moving to SVN 1.7, you should plan to update to SVN 1.9.

Comment: Thanks! Making the dump file from the 1.4 server allowed it to be loaded by the 1.7 server. Also, SVN 1.7 was just what came with CentOS7, but I'll make sure to upgrade to the latest.